# Is it possible to list methods of an .asmx web service?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I am now using [ksoap2](http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/doc/api/) to get data from Web service to my Android phone.

I want to get methods and put them into an `ArrayList`. Is it possilble?

[image]

Is it possible to get all `method` from `URL` of web service?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call all methods by specifing the method name for each call.
eg:

```
 public static String connect(String methodName, String[] args,String[] values) {

        try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(YOUR_NAMESPACE, methodName);
        int i = 0;

        for (String s : args) {
            PropertyInfo propInfo = new PropertyInfo();
            propInfo.name = s;
            propInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            request.addProperty(propInfo, values[i]);
            i++;
        }
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                YOUR_URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(YOUR_NAMESPACE + methodName, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                .getResponse(); // Receiving return string

        String result = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
        return "";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            Log.d("Web Service Exception", ex.toString());
            return "";
        }
    }
```

and use helper methods like

```
public static String Get_ID(parameter) {
        String[] args = new String[1];
        String[] values = new String[1];

        args[0] = "parameter";

        values[0] = parameter;

        String result = connect("Get_ID", args, values);

        return result;
    }
```

If you have more than one method then repeate the helper method with specific parameter and method name. Then this helper methods can be called for getting data in your activity.

Comment: I had updated my question. Could you see that it is possible or not? Thank  you so much for your consideration.

Comment: yes you can. If you want to access each method , first create a helper method like the above mentioned. Then specify parameters as argument.